# How to use a more up to date Cordova plugin in Visual Studio 2017

Tags: cordova, visual-studio-2017, tools-for-apache-cordova

I recently added the Camera and File plugins to my Ionic 1.3/ Cordova app, and now the app is intermittently crashing on the Android device I am using.

The crash is not happening when I am actually using the plugins, nonetheless I wanted to see if the problem would go away if I used more up to date plugins.

If I remove the Camera plugin and add it again, I can see this in the output window:

> Warning: Unmet project requirements for latest version of
>   cordova-plugin-camera: Warning:     cordova-android (5.2.1 in project,
>
> > =6.3.0 required) Warning: Fetching highest version of cordova-plugin-camera that this project supports: 2.4.1 (latest is
> >     4.0.2)

Currently in Visual Studio 2017 you can specify a Toolset that uses Cordova 6.3.1 or a Global Cordova version, so I thought I would try using the latest version of Cordova and on a command line entered: `npm install -g cordova`. I had to restart my computer, but now in my config.xml I can choose "Global Cordova 8.0.0".

Now, in order to use the latest Camera plugin I need to get the `cordova-android` platform `>=6.3.0`. But if I use `cordova platform add android`, it fails because that command needs to be run inside a Cordova-based project.

So I navigate to my existing project folder and run `cordova platform add android` again. It tries to fetch `cordova-android@5.2.1` - so I guess it's now using cordova 6.3.1, because that's the local version. `<edit>` Wrong! - `cordova -v` tells me it's 8.0.0, so it must be choosing `5.2.0` for some other reason.`</edit>`

So what do I need to do now? Do I need to uninstall the local cordova from a command line? Do I delete the existing node_modules, platforms, plugins folders? Do I change the config.xml? (current example entry: - `<plugin name="cordova-plugin-camera" spec="~2.4.1" />`. If I do all that then decide I need to go back to using Visual Studio's toolset, will I have to keep copies of everything and install manually or can I just go back and select the 6.3.1 toolset again?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Changing the Cordova CLI version in Visual Studio 2017 is not as straightforward as it would appear.

Here are the steps I had to follow to change to **Cordova 7.1.0** and **cordova-android 6.3.0**, surely it will allow you to move to [Cordova 8.0](https://cordova.apache.org/news/2017/12/18/tools-release.html) and [cordova-android 7.1.0](https://cordova.apache.org/announcements/2018/02/26/cordova-android-7.1.0.html) as well.

Follow these steps:

Go to `File > New > Project > Blank App (Apache Cordova)`

Open `config.xml` in View Code mode and find this:

```
<vs:toolsetVersion>6.3.1</vs:toolsetVersion>
<engine name="android" spec="5.2.1" />
```

Replace with:

```
<vs:toolsetVersion>8.0.0</vs:toolsetVersion>
<engine name="android" spec="7.1.0" />
```

Where `8.0.0` is your globally installed Cordova version.

Select `Device` as target.

Now `Build > Build Solution`

Save, close and reload the project. When you access `config.xml` in designer mode you'll see **Global Cordova 8.0.0** as the selected toolset.

[image]

In order to build you may need to use the external Android SDK Build Tools (API 27 I guess - it was API 26 for CLI 7.1.0) instead of the ones provided by Visual Studio (API 25).

[image]

Use the [Android SDK Manager](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41407396/is-gui-for-android-sdk-manager-gone) to manage versions, no need to get Android Studio for this.

[image]

Remember to follow [the **guidelines** from Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/cross-platform/tools-for-cordova/change-cordova-version/change-cli-version?view=toolsforcordova-2015) when changing the CLI on existing projects. However I strongly recommend creating a new one and then importing your files and adding your plugins to avoid potential problems.

Comment: I haven't actually tried this answer out myself, because the crash I was getting went away after I went though an exercise of removing and re-adding all my plugins. I must have somehow got a plugin that was incompatible with my version of Cordova.

Comment: @Colin after changing the CLI version, you must remove and re-add all plugins. This a good practice to check for possible incompatibilities and to renew your plugins. I'm glad this answer helped you.

Comment: absolutely. But I didn't actually change the CLI version. I didn't need to. I might do it now that I know how.

Answer (score 1):

After a few try i have found a way:

**Follow this steps:**

1. install nodejs **4.8.7** on your machine
2. in visual studio go under tools>options>"Tools for apache cordova" and deflag chekbox **"use a sandboxed version of NodeJS"**
3. Edit **taco.json** file of your project and set **"cordova-cli": "7.1.0"**
4. Open a new console and install cordova on your machine (**npm install -g cordova@7.1.0**)

**For android build:**

1. open prompt, digit android and press return
2. download **API 26 SDK** from tool
3. download **gradle 2.x** and put bin folder in your system path
4. install **jdk 1.8.x** and set **java_home** system var to it
5. reboot the system

Hope it help.